# What does it mean when a package is in the go/pkg/mod/cache dir but it has no source code extracted?

Tags: go

I'm trying to understand how the source code for third-party dependencies is or is not compiled into my Go binary. I'm building in a Docker container, so I can see precisely what's fetched for my build without interference from other builds.

After my `go build` completes I see source code files for several dependencies under `go/pkg/mod/$module@$version` directories. The [Module cache documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-cache) tells me that these directories contain "extracted contents of a module .zip file. This serves as a module root directory for a downloaded module." My best guess is that the presence of extracted source code for these dependencies indicates that "yes, these dependencies are definitely compiled into your binary."

I also see many more dependencies pulled into `go/pkg/mod/cache/download/$module` directories. The [Module cache documentation](https://golang.org/ref/mod#module-cache) tells me that this directory contains "files downloaded from module proxies and files derived from version control systems," which I don't fully understand. As far as I can see, these files do not include any extracted source code, though there are several `.zip` files that I assume contain the source. For the most part these files seem to be `.mod` files that just contain text representing some sort of dependency graph.

My question is: **if a third-party dependency has module files under `go/pkg/mod/cache/download` but no source code under `go/pkg/mod/$module@$version`, does that mean that dependency's code was NOT compiled into my Go binary?**

I don't understand why the Go build pulls in all these module files but only has extracted source code for some of the third-party modules. Perhaps Go preemptively parses and pulls module information for the full transitive set of modules referenced from the modules my first-party code imports, but perhaps many of those modules don't end up being needed for my binary's compile + build process and therefore don't get extracted. If that's not true and the answer to my question is no, then I don't understand how or why my binary can link in those dependencies without `go build` fetching their source code.

Comment: I'm not quite grasp the essense of your question. `go build` is able to pull the source code from those ZIP-archives containing modules, but since it _compiles_ that source code, it _itself_ is not, of course, included in the resulting executable image file—rather, its compiled form is. But the real question is: why bother—as long as it works as intended? I mean, the resulting binary is compiled and is working OK?

Comment: One more thing: did you try building with a clean cache—that is, after running `go clean -cache`? May be in this case you won't find "strange" modules cached in the cache?

Comment: I need to know exactly what's included in the binary for compliance reasons. The build is running in a Docker container, so the `go/pkg/mod` directory is created from scratch every time.

Comment: OK, that solves the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) which is a step forward. I have tried to address this root problem in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Compile and install packages and dependencies](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_install_packages_and_dependencies)"

> Compiled packages are cached automatically.

[`GOPATH` and Module](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-GOPATH_and_Modules) includes:

> When using modules, GOPATH is no longer used for resolving imports.
> However, it is still used to store downloaded source code (in `GOPATH/pkg/mod`) and compiled commands (in `GOPATH/bin`).

So if you see sources in `pkg/mod` which are not in `pkg/mod/cache`, try a [`go mod tidy`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Module_maintenance)

> add missing and remove unused modules

From there, you should have the same modules between sources (`pkg/mod`) and compiled modules (`pkg/mod/cache`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the OP's comment

> I need to know exactly what's included in the binary for compliance reasons.

I would recommend a completely different approach: dumping the list of symbols contained in the binary and then correlating it with whatever information is needed.

The command

```sh
go tool nm -type /path/to/the/executable/image/file
```

would dump the symbols — names of the functions — whose code was taken from both the standard library packages, 3rd-party and/or vendored packages and internal packages, compiled and linked into the binary, and print to its standard output stream a sequence of lines

```
address type name
```

which you can then process programmatically.

Another approach you might employ is to use `go list` with various flags to query the program's source code about the packages and/or modules which will be used when building: whatever that command outputs describing the full dependency graph of the source code is whatever `go build` will use when building — provided the source code is not changed between these calls.

Yet another possibility is to build the program using `go build -x`, save the debug trace it produces on its standard error stream and parsing it for exact module names the command reported as used during building.